# Avoid repetition of Generic of Generic type

Tags: java, generics

Given the following class/interface structure:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
  T getType();
}

public class MyClassA<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
  // ...
}
public class MyClassB<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
  // ...
}

public MyClassWrapper<T> implements MyInterface<T> {

  private MyInterface<T> delegate;

  public MyClassWrapper(MyInterface<T> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public T getType() {
    this.delegate.getType();
  }

  // ...
}
```

I want to add a method `getDelegate()` to `MyClassWrapper` that should not return `MyInterface<T>` but the actual implementation of `MyInterface` that was used to create the wrapper. I came up with this:

```
public MyClassWrapper<T, M extends MyInterface<T>> implements MyInterface<T> {

  private M delegate;

  public MyClassWrapper(M delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public M getDelegate() {
    return this.delegate;
  }

  // ...
}
```

This of course works but is very inconvenient to use as I always have to specify the type `T` twice:

```
MyClassWrapper<String, MyClassA<String>> wrapper = new MyClassWrapper<>(new MyClassA<>(String.class));
```

For `String` this might look "ok" but it becomes very cumbersome, for longer type names... Is there some way to avoid the need to specify the first generic type of `MyClassWrapper`. Basically I want to achieve this:

```
MyClassWrapper<MyClassA<String>> wrapper = new MyClassWrapper<>(new MyClassA<>(String.class));
MyClassA<String> delegate = wrapper.getDelegate(); // no cast here!!
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just refer to delegate, so; public MyInterface<T> getDelegate() { return delegate }?

Comment: That would return `MyInterface<T>` (at least in it's signature) but I want to get the correct type (depending on the type used to create the wrapper) in the signature as well. That is `MyClassA<T> getDelegate()` but generic...

Comment: Can you define `class MyClassAStringWrapper extends MyClassWrapper<MyClassA<String>>` perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, good point Andy, that would be the only way you could do it which would be to define a wrapper for each class that extends MyInterface.

Comment: @AndyTurner that would mean to introduce a new wrapper class for each possibly wrapped type.

Comment: @dpr I agree it's not ideal, but there's got to be a compromise somewhere.

Comment: @AndyTurner, if I have the 2 options "subclass `MyClassWrapper` multiple types" or "live with the cumbersome generics", I'd choose the latter one...